# Buck Build Rules For Sub-Projects

Tags: android, cordova, buck

Our project uses Cordova and a number of other sub-projects.

I read through the Buck documentation and start guide a few times and have been experimenting with building simple projects. I am now attempting to migrate our project over to using Buck (and Exopackage).

From the AntennaPod sample I see how to bundle the src files, the assets, and res into a project. However I am not clear on what build rules I need to follow to bundle sub-projects into the main one.

Can you point out the build rules I need that will add sub-projects to my main build or explain what I need to add to my main BUCK file that will properly organize and build sub-projects.

Below is a screen shot of our project structure with one of the sub-projects expanded.

The sub-projects I need to build and add are:

**xwalk_core_library**

**CordovaLib**

**Cordova**

**com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect**

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create as many `android_library` and `android_resource` rules that you want.  The important thing is to make sure you set your `deps` correctly.  The final APK will contain all the transitive `deps` you specify.

Comment: So for example CordovaLib would be an android_library (not a separate binary?)

Comment: Yeah, just make another `android_library` and make sure you depend on it.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude transitive dependency from final APK? To avoid "error: Attribute *** has already been defined". E.g. if main project depends on lib_1 and subproject depends on lib_1 too.

Comment: @surlac - that should be fine assuming it only exists in one library.  If it gets defined in more than one `android_library`, I'd expect to see that error, however.